# Error GenerateAppxPackageRecipe task was not given a value for the required parameter "ProjectDir"

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I want to build my first application in visual studio 2012, but I  get this error

```
Error 1  The "GenerateAppxPackageRecipe" task was not given a value for the required  
parameter "ProjectDir".
TestHelloWorld
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error recently.  I have been experimenting with VS2012 Update 1, installing and uninstalling to test builds.  I suspect that install, uninstall, and other fiddling caused the problem -- I am unsure exactly what state I was in when this error occurred.  So, I did the following:

- Uninstalled the VS2012 Update 1 update.
- Uninstalled VS2012 Express.
- Uninstalled VS2012 Ultimate.
- Rebooted.
- Installed VS2012 Express.
- Installed VS2012 Ultimate.
- Cleaned my project working copy.

After following this sequence, I opened up a Windows Store app solution again, and I was able to successfully build the solution again.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with VS2012 Update 1.  Working on a solution, but in the meantime, you can simplify the steps: just remove Update 1 and repair the VS install, like this:

1. Go to Control Panel->Programs and Features.
2. Click "View Installed Updates"
3. Select VS2012 Update 1 and Uninstall it.
4. Now click "Uninstall a program".
5. Select Visual Studio 2012 and click Change.
6. Click Repair.
7. Reboot.